# selecting values for forms in php and mysql data changes

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Table

```
colorid -        1      2       3    4 
color            blue  yellow  green red 
currentcolor     yes    no     no    no
```

This is the database. I have a PHP code that gives you a form to select the color you would like to make current. It gives the colors options. Once you select the color say in this example if you select green and click submit it should have value for currentcolor for color green as yes and automatically change the value for current color for blue to no... How can I achieve this in SQL or php? Right now I only have

```
update color (table) sent currentcolor = 'yes' where color = $info['color']
```

which will change the value of currentcolor for the selected color to yes but still keep the value yes for currentcolor for the previous color. 
Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd have an easier life if you'd change the db structure. Store the `currentcolor` in a seperate table (maybe a 'meta' table with only the colorid)

Comment: Other possibility is to set currentcolor to NO for _all_ rows _before_ you set the one currentcolor.

Comment: consider one of the answers to accept it, when it solved your problem! (@PHPWeb|s is the best I think)

Comment: Yes Thanks Jeff, I saw @PHPWebs after I implemented your solution. I think it is the best too and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this update statement to solve your purpose :-

```
$sql = "update color
        set currentcolor = CASE
        WHEN color = '".$info['color']."' THEN 'yes'
        ELSE 'no'
        END" ;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

With your current structure you have two possibilities:

```
// set all colours to no before setting the current one:
update color set currentcolor = 'no'
// then
update color set currentcolor = 'yes' where color = $info['color']
```

OR

```
// set those to NO, which are not the current colous
update color set currentcolor = 'no' where color != $info['color']
```

Anyway, I think you'd be better off to store `currentcolor` in another table, let's call it meta

```
table META
item                value 
--------------------------
currentcolor        2
currentbackground   35
.
.
.
```

Answer (score -1):

Set all values of current color to "no" before setting the new one to yes.